# Minimum number of variables for factor analysis?

Tags: factor-analysis

Is there a minimum number of input variables that an exploratory factor analysis requires?

Comment: Mathematically, two. For more practical & statistical reasons, three at least. This is because there is a rule of thumb that each factor should decently load at least 3 variables. Also, number of cases should be at least 5 times than the number of variables; however, if variables are many (i.e. 100+), this coefficient may go lower (say, 2-3 times).

Comment: @ttnphns Mathematically, one will do.

Comment: @whuber, any correlations?

Comment: @ttnphns Yes: the variance-covariance matrix of one variable is a $1\times 1$ matrix.  In `R` you can carry out such a factor analysis with a command like `princomp(covmat=matrix(2))`.  If you want factor analysis *per se,* this will do it: `library(psych);  fa(matrix(2))`.

Comment: @whuber, It's pity (for R). Anyway, this is too a trivial case for (exploratory) _factor_ analysis. With your permission, I replace "mathematically" with "conceptually", which is better.